# Need a script to continuous automatic file movement from one folder to another with file extension of txt

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I need a script for task scheduler which allows me to move files from one folder to another for txt file type only. Which means when I drop a txt file into a folder it needs to be moved to another folder immediately. If I put any file other than txt the file should not move. This txt file movement need to 24*7 service.

I have used the below script but it is moving all types of file including BAT file. Also not working continuously. It's needed to be run manually from task scheduler to move the file.

```
@echo off
set "source=H:\Source\Send"
set "destination=F:\Destination>"

For /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR %source%\*.txt /A:-D /O:-D /B') DO COPY %SOURCE%\ "%%I" %target% & echo %%I & GOTO :END
:END
```

Comment: Is the `>` just a typo in the question? Also, I would definitely recommend start writing scripts using powershell. That will help a lot the moment you need to do anything bit more complex.

Comment: `COPY %SOURCE%\ "%%I" %target%`? I guess it should be `COPY "%SOURCE%\%%I" "%target%"`

Comment: I think your whole idea is crazy, I would suggest you drop them onto a script instead of into a folder, or have a context menu item which runs the script or its commands. Alternatively you could just use `RoboCopy` once at startup, with its `/Mov` option coupled with one of either `/Mon:` or `/Mot:`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that will check once a second for `.txt` files and move them.  I designed it to be a script that runs a continuous loop.  You can start it with the task scheduler and run it with the task scheduler on a repeating schedule.  It checks for itself and will not run again if there is another instance already running.  It does not have error checking included.
**UNTESTED**

```
@echo off

:: Use the parameter AuTosTaRt to start the actual loop.
:: This parameter should never be used directly/manually.
:: It should only be used by this script file to start itself.

if "%1"=="AuTosTaRt" goto :beginmove

:: Check if this script is already running
:: Note that it seems like there should be a better
:: reliable way to do this, but this is what I've
:: found over the years.

:: If the script is already running then exit.
:: Sometimes the windowtitle includes Administrator
tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq Administrator: Move text files"| find /i "cmd.exe" >nul && goto :eof
:: Sometimes the windowtitle doesn't include Administrator
tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq Move text files"| find /i "cmd.exe" >nul && goto :eof

:: Sometimes there is an odd timing issue where the script
:: is running but somehow the above lines do not find it.
:: Wait 5 seconds and check again just to make sure.
timeout /t 5 >nul
tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq Administrator: Move text files"| find /i "cmd.exe" >nul && goto :eof
tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq Move text files"| find /i "cmd.exe" >nul && goto :eof

:: If we get here, then the script isn't running.  Let's start it:
start "Move text files" /min cmd /d /c "%~dpnx0" AuTosTaRt
goto :eof



:beginmove
set "source=H:\Source\Send"
set "destination=F:\Destination"

:loop
move "%source%\*.txt" "%destination%" >nul 2>nul
:: Pause 1 second.  We don't need the loop to go crazy.
timeout /t 1 >nul
goto :loop
```

Comment: Big thanks.... the script worked perfectly......  you are truly a life saver,... :)